# Impressão em HTML - PHP

Tags: php, html, impressão

Seguinte... Tenho uma estrutura HTML formada por TABS, a estilo destas do link:
http://www.codecovers.eu/materialadmin/ui/tabs#second1
Porém na hora de imprimir com Ctrl+p apenas chama a TAB que encontra-se Ativa. Como faço para que a impressão imprima o conteúdo de todas as TABS?

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-head">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-toggle="tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#first1">FIRST TAB</a></li>
                <li><a href="#second1">NO. TWO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#third1">THE THIRD</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--end .card-head -->
    <div class="card-body tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="first1">                        
           <p>Per at postea mediocritatem, vim numquam aliquid eu, in nam sale gubergren. Fuisset delicatissimi duo, qui ut animal noluisse erroribus. Ea eum veniam audire. Dicant vituperata consequuntur.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="second1">                     
           <p>Ad ius duis dissentiunt, an sit harum primis persecuti, adipisci tacimates mediocrem sit et. Id illud voluptaria omittantur qui, te affert nostro mel. Cu conceptam vituperata temporibus has.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="third1">                      
           <p>Duo semper accumsan ea, quidam convenire cum cu, oportere maiestatis incorrupte est eu. Soluta audiam timeam ius te, idque gubergren forensibus ad mel, persius urbanitas usu id. Civibus nostrum fabellas mea te, ne pri lucilius iudicabit. Ut cibo semper vituperatoribus vix, cum in error elitr. Vix molestiae intellegat omittantur an, nam cu modo ullum scriptorem.</p>
        <p>Quod option numquam vel in, et fuisset delicatissimi duo, qui ut animal noluisse erroribus. Ea eum veniam audire. Per at postea mediocritatem, vim numquam aliquid eu, in nam sale gubergren. Dicant vituperata consequuntur at sea, mazim commodo</p>
        </div>
    </div><!--end .card-body -->
</div><!--end .card -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar uma regra especifica de CSS para quando imprimes, e que força o que está escondido com `display: none;` a estar visivel quando é para imprimir.

No teu HTML seria algo assim:

```
@media print {
    .tab-pane {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

Podes colocar esse código no teu ficheiro de CSS ou na página HTML assim:

```
<style>
@media print {
    .tab-pane {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Onde eu coloco este código?

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto juntei esse exemplo à resposta também.

Comment: Ok. Funciona bem, porém deixa a desejar em um ponto. talvez consiga me dar mais este auxilio.... Os título da Tab1 e Tab2 ficam antes dos dois conteúdos na impressão. Teria como o título da tab2 pular para antes do conteúdo da mesma na impressão?

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto sim e não. Uma vez que esses elementos DOM não estão junto uns aos outros isso vai ser complicado. Ou crias outros elementos que tenham essa função e só os mostras na impressão  (escondendo os atuais) ou posicionas tudo com posições defenidas para teres controlo sobre o posicionamento.

Comment: Pois é, acho que não entendi o que quer dizer Sergio.

Comment: Consegui Sergio. Criei títulos com display 'none' em cima dos conteúdos. Desta forma quando for imprimir eu ativo os títulos e escondo o título principal das TABS. Sua solução foi ótima :)

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto boa! Eu estava ausente mas pela tua descrição acho que já percebeste o que eu me referia. Se tiveres mais duvidas podes perguntar aqui ou numa nova pergunta. Até breve

Comment: Tenho algo relacionado ainda à impressão. Caso queira responder aqui mesmo. Geralmente o que for link, a impressão traz o caminho inteiro e não a palavra real do link. Tem como modificar?

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto sim. Agora não tenho como testar mas acho que tens de mexer no content como aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14931127/2256325 -> isso é na verdade uma pergunta interessante e útil que podia estar como pergunta separada para futuras necessidades de outros.

Comment: Show. Ficou padrão cara :D